# AlertDialog с темой Material Disign криво отображается с API < 21

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

У меня есть `AlertDialog`, на который я пробовал устанавливать разные темы.

В новых андроидах он отображается нормально, а в старых - гг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в импортах.

Я пытался установить тему MD на `android.app.AlertDialog`, а не на `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`.

К тому же поддерживаемый `AlertDialog` самостоятельно переводит кнопки в вертикальную ориентацию, если они не помещаются.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вам воспользоваться **DialogFragment**(ом) он работает с **API >=11**.

Он лучше подходит, если вы хотите расположить элементы кастомно и назначить свое поведение.

**DialogFragment** является наследником класса **Fragment** и отличается от него тем, что отображается как диалог и имеет соответствующие методы.

Более подробно о том как его использовать есть в документации - [ссылка на офф. документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html?hl=ru).

Comment: Я по некоторым причинам не работаю с фрагментами. Хотелось бы найти другое решение